# Salesforce queue email notification customize and auto trigger based on time

Tags: scheduled-apex, time-dependent-workflow, queue

In my Salesforce Org, I got a custom object and queue. when a new custom object record created will assign to this queue by workflow. My question is how to accomplish following task:

If this record own by queue more than 3 days, then an email notification will send to all queue members

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this using a Time based workflow:

1) Create a workflow rule and select
 **Evaluate  the rule when a record is: 
created**

2) In the criteria select
**Record Owner = Queue ID**

3) Add the **Time-Dependent Workflow Actions** (in your case it will be an email alert) with **time trigger** as 3 days after Rule trigger date